# I am trying to use GoogleAPI YouTube to get details about YouTube Videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Using GoogleAPI v3 url
using this url:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=D-wxnID2q4A&key={MyKey}

I get this json:

```
    {
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/uzqDS1yLcX0DglL60bHeS56kZ7c\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/l7OMkGqgmC10NvbO5PzI_nonZzA\"",
   "id": "D-wxnID2q4A",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-01-08T05:34:04.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCtA7mzeypl_udtFySMXTusQ",
    "title": "Can You Walk on Water? (Non-Newtonian Fluid Pool)",
    "description": "Running, jumping and biking on 8,000 litres of non-newtonian fluid in Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia! Brought to you by Mach by Hong Leong Bank together with We are KIX. Music and info below..\n\nGet Banking with Mach by Hong Leong Bank: http://www.machbyhongleongbank.com\n\nA film and event concept by: http://www.wearekix.com\n\nFeatured Runner: https://www.caykuijpers.com\n\nMUSIC by Thrill me now & Ion Ray: https://soundcloud.com/thrillmenow/walk-on-water-canyouwalkonwater-soundtrack\n\nHosted at: The Square Publika \nDance Crew: http://www.facebook.com/KatoonNetworkDanceCrew\nLive DJ and Sound Effects by: http://www.facebook.com/weare2db\nLive DJ's: http://www.facebook.com/deersociety",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/D-wxnID2q4A/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/D-wxnID2q4A/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/D-wxnID2q4A/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/D-wxnID2q4A/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/D-wxnID2q4A/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Mach by Hong Leong Bank",
    "categoryId": "24",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
    "localized": {
     "title": "Can You Walk on Water? (Non-Newtonian Fluid Pool)",
     "description": "Running, jumping and biking on 8,000 litres of non-newtonian fluid in Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia! Brought to you by Mach by Hong Leong Bank together with We are KIX. Music and info below..\n\nGet Banking with Mach by Hong Leong Bank: http://www.machbyhongleongbank.com\n\nA film and event concept by: http://www.wearekix.com\n\nFeatured Runner: https://www.caykuijpers.com\n\nMUSIC by Thrill me now & Ion Ray: https://soundcloud.com/thrillmenow/walk-on-water-canyouwalkonwater-soundtrack\n\nHosted at: The Square Publika \nDance Crew: http://www.facebook.com/KatoonNetworkDanceCrew\nLive DJ and Sound Effects by: http://www.facebook.com/weare2db\nLive DJ's: http://www.facebook.com/deersociety"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I am using C# (Nuget) GoogleAPI for YouTube, I have given API permission and received my key for v3.

My C# code is:

```
 var      VideoID = "D-wxnID2q4A";
 var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApiKey = APT.core.Properties.Settings.Default.GoogleKey,
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
            });


            var t=  youtubeService.Videos.List("part=snippet,id="+VideoID);
```

This throws the exception :

```
Exception:Thrown: "Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
No filter selected. [400]
Errors [
    Message[No filter selected.] Location[ - parameter] Reason[missingRequiredParameter] Domain[youtube.parameter]
]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
    var VideoID = "D-wxnID2q4A";
    var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        ApiKey = "{YOUR-API-KEY}",
        ApplicationName = "YouTube-test"
    });

    var t = youtubeService.Videos.List("snippet");
    t.Id = VideoID;
    var listResponse = t.Execute();
```

`listResponse` should then contain the information you require.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public List<VideoItem> GetCurrentChannelVideos()
    {
        var channelsListRequest = youtube.Channels.List("contentDetails");
        channelsListRequest.Mine = true;
        // Retrieve the contentDetails part of the channel resource for the authenticated user's channel.
        var channelsListResponse = channelsListRequest.Execute();
        //List<VideoLink> allVideos = new List<VideoLink>();
        List<VideoItem> allVideos = new List<VideoItem>();
        foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
        {
            // From the API response, extract the playlist ID that identifies the list
            // of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
            var uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;
            var nextPageToken = "";
            while (nextPageToken != null)
            {
                var playlistItemsListRequest = youtube.PlaylistItems.List("snippet,status");
                playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
                playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
                playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;

                // Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
                var playlistItemsListResponse = playlistItemsListRequest.Execute();
                allVideos.AddRange(playlistItemsListResponse.Items.Select(s => new VideoItem() { VideoID = s.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId, ThumbnailURL = s.Snippet.Thumbnails.Default__.Url, Title = s.Snippet.Title }).ToList());
                nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;

            }
        }
        return allVideos;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Please review carefully. This post doesn't contain any link.